# How do I define QML states dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, qt, dynamic, qml

Is there any way of creating a state object dynamically using a javascript loop for instance.

Result should look like:

```
states: [
    State{
        name: "name1"
        when: somevar === onevar

        //stuff
    },
    State{
        name: "name2"
        when: somevar === anothervar

        //stuff
    }
]
```

but I want to start with an arbitrary javascript array, like

```
var myStatesObj = [{
    "name": "name1"
    "condition": onevar
},{
    "name": "name2"
    "condition": anothervar
}]
```

and use a loop to create the states QML object.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests and I don't think you can dynamically modify the states list (seems like it's an object and no array internally)!?

Here my tests:
create a dynamic state (that does work with a Component template)

```
Component {
    id: stateTemplate
    State {}
}

// then use this code to create an state object
var st = stateTemplate.createObject(parent, { name: "testSate", when: yourCondition })
```

try to add the state

```
states.push(st) // error because "states" is not an array!?
states[states.length] = st // no error but the stages object didn't change at all?
```

You can iterate though all the existing states and everything, but it seems the states object is not changeable or am I missing something here?